# Why Does Linux Mint Not Connect to the Internet Through Ethernet Cable?

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet

For some reason my linux mint v20.1 has not been able to connect to the internet through the ethernet cable that is plugged into it. I know that the ethernet cable is not the problem because it works with other computers. This computer was also working with the ethernet cable a few days ago. The ethernet port is glowing orange, meaning that it is not an external problem because it is detecting it.
This is the output of lspci (for broadcom):

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
```

This is the output of lsmod (for tg3):

```
tg3      172032  0
```

And when I tell system log with this command to report that the card has been initialized there is no output:

```
dmesg | grep ether
```

This is also has no output:

```
dmesg | grep -i eno1
```

But this does, meaning (I think) that the cable is called eth0:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

The output (I have to type this out so I am going to use some imaginary variables)
x = [     1.629770]
y = 0000:02:00.0

```
x tg3 y eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM57780) rev 57780001] (PCI Express) MAC address 14:fe:b5:df:5a:0c
x tg3 y eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
x tg3 y eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
x tg3 y enp2s0: renamed from eth0
```

but actually, it has been renamed to enp2s0.
So I tried this:

```
ifconfig enp2s0
```

Output:

```
enp2s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
     ether 14:fe:b5:df:5a:0c txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
     RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
     RX error - dropped 0 overruns 0   frame 0 
     TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
     TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0   carrier 0   collisions 0 
     device interrupt 16
```

This is a remade version of my original post: [Why Won't Linux Mint Connect With Ethernet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654028/why-wont-linux-mint-connect-with-ethernet)

I added a lot more information that will hopefully help with figuring out the issue.

Comment: How do you configure the network interfaces? Manually, network-manager,...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think you found it. This means that the card is installed and recognized:

```
enp2s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
     ether 14:fe:b5:df:5a:0c txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
     RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
     RX error - dropped 0 overruns 0   frame 0 
     TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
     TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0   carrier 0   collisions 0 
     device interrupt 16
```

But notice that **there is no IP address listed**? This means that the ethernet card *is not configured*. You need to enter a configuration using either NetworkManager, netplan, or whatever system your distro is using.

To quickly check whether it's working you can configure it manually (here I assume you have a router at 192.168.1.1 and you can use the 192.168.1.137 address):

```
ifconfig enp2s0 192.168.1.137 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add -net default gw 192.168.1.1
```

Now you should be able to ping 192.168.1.1 and, if Internet is connected, something farther like one of the Google nodes at 8.8.8.8.

You may want to do a

```
grep -r eth0 /etc
```

to see whether there *is* a configuration extant, it's simply not working because it uses the old `eth0` moniker instead of the `enp2s0`.

Comment: This solution did not work at first. I was scrambling around trying to manually configure stuff when it randomly started to work! Thanks so much, I am going back to making my website : )